# Confusing results from using Float.floatToIntBits() then Integer.toBinaryString()

Tags: java, floating-point

I’m trying to understand how floating point works. When I run this code :

```
float number = 3.0f;
int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(number);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bits));
```

I get :

```
1000000010000000000000000000000
```

But the correct binary format for 3 should be (according to  [this converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)):

```
01000000010000000000000000000000
```

Why isn’t the sign bit (0) displayed by println here?

EDIT : initially, I was using`Long.toBinaryString` instead of `Integer.toBinaryString`

I would get this kind of result :

```
float number = -3.0f;
int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(number);
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(bits));
```

output :

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111000000010000000000000000000000
```

but using `Integer.toBinaryString` return the correct binary format for `-3.0f` :

```
11000000010000000000000000000000
```

Comment: It's just `Long.toBinaryString()` dropping the 0 in front. You can see that there's one digit less than in the one you got from the converter. Nothing wrong with the conversion, you're just displaying it wrong.

Comment: Cannot vote for duplicate since it's closed, but this question is actually a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That just needed a bit of formatting :

```
float number = 3.0f;
int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(number);
String representation = Integer.toBinaryString(bits);
representation = String.format("%32s", representation).replace(' ', '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

`Integer::toBinaryString` will not add zeros up to 32 bits.

```
int x = 0b_000001;
System.out.println(Integer::toBinaryString(x));
```

The result is `1`, not `000...0001`. (32bits)
The heading zeros are omitted.