# How can I look for patterns in the first 3 bits of an int which is assigned from a FileInputStream.read() which returns an int between 0:255 or -1?

Tags: java, io

I am reading bytes as follows:

```
        try(FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("nameOfFile")){
            int readByte = 0;
            int mask =0b111;
            while((readByte=f.read())!=-1) {
                System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(readByte & mask));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However, when i try to obtain the 8 bits that forms the number, sometimes I get 7 bits or even more bits than 8.
Can anyone help me with this problem? I want to get 8 bits so after that i can look at first 3 bits for example. I need that for returning the charset in this method.

I'll be very gratefull if you help me. I am looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Best regards,
WaterKnight

Comment: I'm afraid it's pretty unclear what you are trying to achieve.  You can help us out and thereby make it much more likely that you will receive a useful answer by editing your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "obtain the 8 bits"? Obtain where? You have the 8 bits right there in the `int` (along with 24 more bits). If you want to "look at first 3 bits", go on and look: `readByte & 0x07`. Or if you want to "look": [`Integer.toBinaryString(readByte)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-)

Comment: @JohnBollinger I updated my code , just Would like to look at 3first bits of the int and know if it follows some kind of pattern.

Comment: `110` is a *decimal* number, equals to the *binary* number `0b1101110`, so `(byteLeido[0] >>> 5)==110` will never ever be true. Perhaps you meant `(byteLeido[0] >>> 5) == 0b110` or `(byteLeido[0] >>> 5) == 0x06` or `(byteLeido[0] >>> 5) == 6`?

Comment: @Andreas thats why I am asking to try to look at pattern at 3 or 2 first bits of the int that goes between 0 and 255.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get 0-padded binary representation of an integer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421400/5221149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `byte` is an 8-bit two's-complement signed number.

If you think a byte has values 0..255, then you are wrong. The 8 bits are -128..127, because bit 7 is the sign bit.

When you do bit-manipulation using operators like `>>>`, the `byte` is first widened to an `int`, which means that sign-extension is applied.

So, unsigned value `199` (example), is bits `11000111`, which as a `byte` is value `-57` aka `0xC7`, and when sign-extended to an `int` becomes `-57` aka `0xFFFFFFC7`.

When you right-shift that by 5 (`>>> 5`), you get `0x07FFFFFE` aka `134217726`.

Since you're only interested in the lowest 3 bits of that value, you need to mask it: `(val >>> 5) & 0x07`, which will give you what you're looking for: `0x06` aka `0b110`

Comment: I read that .read() of an input stream returned and int with values 0..255, so as this decimals values are a byte i would like to look into the 3 highest bits from the byte. In adittion, I tried  your solution, System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((readByte >>> 5) & 0x07)); but in console I get lines with 3 bits, other ones with 2 bits and others with 1bit.

Comment: @WaterKnight Did you not read my comment to you in the other answer? Or the link I provided in comment to your question? For your convenience, here both are: "You are getting 3 bits from all of the bytes read. Those are all 3-bit values, but, like any other formatted number, **leading zeroes have been removed**, so e.g. `11` means `011`, and `0` means `000`" and [How to get 0-padded binary representation of an integer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421400/5221149)

Comment: @Andres I just read your comment on the other answer and got it working as follows Integer.toBinaryString(byteLeido>>>5).equals("110"). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[0, 255] range implies that you use all the 8 bits for value, without leaving the most significant bit for the sign.

[`FileInputStream.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileInputStream.html) reads a byte of data. The `int` return type allows to spot the difference between `-1` data and `-1` used to signal end of the stream. In practice `read()` return value won't be greater than 255.

If you want to look at the last 3 bits use a bit mask. You can use binary literal to define your mask:

```
int mask = 0b111;
int lastBits = readBytes & mask;
```

Comment: when I make this i get the next input throught console: 1001100. I am using System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b)); for getting a look into the bits.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod I missed the point of the question, but you are right!

Comment: when I make the things from you updated answer all I get is: 100
11
1
0
1
10
0
1
10
10
100
ANSI. So i am not getting 3 bits from all of the bytes readed.

Comment: @WaterKnight Sure you are getting 3 bits from all of the bytes read. Those are all 3-bit values, but, like any other formatted number, leading zeroes have been removed, so e.g. `11` means `011`, and `0` means `000`.