# Converting Long Object to String in Java

Tags: java

Let's say i have this Long in Java:

```
 Long x=0b01101L;
```

and i want to convert it into a String using this:

```
String str1 = Long.toBinaryString(x);
```

Is there a way to keep the first 0 inside the String?
What i mean is can this:

```
System.out.println(str1);
```

print `01101` and not `1101`?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java

Comment: why only one zero? the long has plenty more zeros (and there is no difference between `Long x=0b01101L;` and `Long x=0b0000000000001101L`, after compilation both are just `13L`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. When you declare `Long x = 0b01101L;`, you create a `long` instance, which contains no information about the `String` representation of the value it contains. Yes, it equals 13 in decimal, but it also equals 十三 in traditional Chinese/Japanese writing, and it also equals 10 + 3, and so on.

If you want to convert it to a `String` padded to a certain number of zeroes, you can use `String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(x)).replace(' ', '0')`, but you must know in advance how many digits you want to be printed, as this will always return 16 digits.

However, this information is not encoded in a `Long` (or `long`). If you need to keep this information, declare your variable as a `String xString = "01101";`, and convert it to a `long` using `Long.valueOf(xString, 2);` when you need to do numerical operations.