# Putting all 8-bit binary sequences into a string array Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

what I am trying to put all possible 256 binary bit sequences into a string array. In order to do that, I have created 8 for loops to have all the possible cases. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
static String[] BitSequences() {    
    int[] result = new int[256];
    for (int a = 0; a < 256; a++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
                    for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++){
                        for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++){
                            for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++){
                                for (int o = 0; o < 2; o++){
                                    for (int p = 0; p < 2; p++){
                                        result[a] = ; //this part is a problem
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    String str = Arrays.toString(result);
    System.out.println(str);
    return str;
}
```

This method is supposed to return a string array that contains all the possible cases. However, I don't know how to insert these value by making for-loops using int values. It is easy to print it out:
'
System.out.println(i+j+k+.....+p)
'
any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you doing this? Is this homework, where you are not allowed to use some built in APIs?

Comment: Since ints are calculated in base 10 you will likely need to turn the individual ints into strings and `concatenate` them together.

Comment: If this is what you decide to do the `Arrays.toString(result);` bit isn't required anymore. The `result` array would need to initialize as a string array.

Comment: Try `result[a] = "" + i + j ... + p";`  to convert; note you will run into trouble with your `a` index

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [the built in conversion method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) for binary strings:

```java
static String[] BitSequences() {    
    String[] result = new String[256];
    for (int a = 0; a < 256; a++) {
        result[a] = Integer.toBinaryString(a);
    }
    String str = Arrays.toString(result);
    System.out.println(str);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An 8-bit, two's complement integer ranges from `-128` to `127`. To represent that range, we can use [`IntStream#rangeClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed(int,int)).

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421452/7294647), we can utilize [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) to left-pad the binary `String` (generated by [`Integer#toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int))) with 0s if its length is less than `8` (denoting that the value is positive).

Otherwise, the value represents a negative number, and its respective binary string will have a length greater than `8`, which must be truncated to `8` characters using [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)).

Finally, the `Stream<String>` can be collected to a `String[]` using [`Stream#toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)).

```
public static String[] generateBitSequences() { 
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(-128, 127)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toBinaryString)
        .map(BigInteger::new)
        .map(b -> String.format("%08d", b))    // Left pad positive values with 0s.
        .map(s -> s.substring(s.length() - 8)) // Remove leading 1s from negative values.
        .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Output:

```
[10000000, 10000001, ..., 01111110, 01111111]
```

Comment: I really like the elegance of this approach, though I thought introducing higher concepts might be a bit less accessible to the questioner. Consider adding references to the methods you're using here.

Comment: @RussellMyers I appreciate the comment and have edited the answer accordingly. Thanks!