# Why doesn't this code output the way I think? (about shift)

Tags: java

```
public static void maain(String[] args){
    int a = -11;
    System.out.println(" a= "+a+"("+Integer.toBinaryString(a)+")");
    System.out.println(" a>>2= "+(a>>2)+"("+Integer.toBinaryString(a>>2)+")");
    System.out.println(" a>>>2= "+(a>>>2)+"("+Integer.toBinaryString(a>>>2)+")");
}
```

I think a>>>2 output is 001111111111111111111111111101, because >>> means shift right and fill blanks with 0. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: As a is negative, I think that the javadocs answers your question.  *The unsigned integer value is the argument plus 2pow(32) if the argument is negative;**

Comment: why do you expect `001111111111111111111111111101` with 30 digits and not `00111111111111111111111111111101` with 32 digits (or `111111111111111111111111111101` with 30 digits) ?? An `int` has 32 bits but `toBinaryString()` does not *show* leading zeros

Comment: maybe the output from that [code](https://ideone.com/gVC20K) is better to see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that `Integer.toBinaryString()` outputs leading zeros? The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) clearly states otherwise:

> If the unsigned magnitude is zero, it is represented by a single zero character '0' ('\u0030'); otherwise, the first character of the representation of the unsigned magnitude will not be the zero character.

Java doesn't offer a built-in method to convert an integer into a binary representation with leading zeros. Several possible solutions are offered at [How to get 0-padded binary representation of an integer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421400/how-to-get-0-padded-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-java)

For example you could use:

```
System.out.println(" a>>>2= "+(a>>>2)+"("+String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(a>>>2)).replace(' ', '0')+")");
```