# How to create a fixed lenght blank String in a smart way?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have the following situation and I am not sure if I am handling it in smart way.

So I have to create a textual file that contains some lines.

Each line is a String composed by the concatenation of some other strings.

Some of these string (that I have to concatenate) are taken from a model object (are the values of the fields definied into a model object).

Some other string have fixed value (with fixed lenght).

For example (into the method that create the concatenation) I could have something like this:

```
// FINAL BUILDED String:
String outputLine;

// FIELDS TO BE CONCATENATED:
String jobId = "        ";
String address = myModelObject.getAddress();
String name = myModelObject.getName();

outputLine = jobId + address + name;
```

So, as you can see from the previous snippet, the **jobId** field have to be a fixed String composed by **8 blanks consecutive characters**

My doubt is: is it correct or can I crete a fixed lenght String (composed by all blanks characters) in some smarter way? Maybe using an **array of Char**? But I am not sure that it is a smarter solution

Tnx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a string with n characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804827/create-a-string-with-n-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common method is to use `Arrays.fill`.

```
public static String makeFilledString(int n, char c) {
    char[] ca = new char[n];
    Arrays.fill(ca, c);
    return new String(ca);
}
```

No idea whether this is more or less efficient than just building one in a loop but at least it allows you to configure your field widths instead of hiding their lengths behind a hard-coded string.

Note that this technique **always creates a new String**. This *may* result in more memory being used that you would wish. It can be beneficial to keep track of them in a `Map` so you don't repeat the creations.

```
private static Map<Integer, String> spaces = new HashMap<>();

public static String spaces(int n) {
    String s = spaces.get(n);
    if (s == null) {
        spaces.put(n, s = makeFilledString(n, ' '));
    }
    return s;
}
```

NB: The above is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 3):

Java `Strings` are always *immutable*. They cannot be changed. 
`String jobId = "        ";` is a *String Literal* and is shared by all classes in the JVM. i.e, anything that comes within double quotes `""` goes into the String constants pool and will have only one instance *irrespective* from where it is being used.

Next, `outputLine = jobId + address + name;` uses `StringBuilder` internally. So, there is nothing much that can be done here.

Two things that have to be checked while using Strings :

1. Never use `string.concat()` in a *loop* (unless you want to show someone that it is a bad idea :P).
2. Never create `new String("someStringLiteral")` (unless you want to show someone that it is a bad idea as well :P).

PS : If you are certain that some string will be used only few times, you could do `new String(charArray[])` and keep it on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is to format the output string, if this is the case, you can use String.format:

```
outputLine = String.format("%8s%s%s", s1, s2, s3);
```

If you need your String to have a fixed length, you can create an utility method:

```
public static String fillString(String string, char character, int size) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
    sb.append(string);
    while (sb.length() < size) {
        sb.insert(0, character);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```