# Showing dynamic output in console using Java

Tags: java, scripting, console-application

When using `curl`, I've noticed that it outputs to the terminal text that can be then later replaced and updated. This 'dynamic' text output is what I'd like to do.

Specifically:

An execution like: `curl http://raw.github.com/someGZippedPackage | gunzip`
shows the percentage completion and a completion bar *in the terminal*.

Are there libraries that provide this functionality?

I can use any object-oriented programming language.

Preferably built for either Java or Node.js.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with `This 'dynamic' text output is what I'd like to do.` Can you clarify what you're looking for?  Curl will retrieve html pages, and either dump them to file(s) or display them as text.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my ambiguity; I've edited my response and hopefully it is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a **progress bar**,
which can be generated without curses, by using backspace and carriage return characters.

This makes your question a duplicate of [Command line progress bar in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852665/command-line-progress-bar-in-java)

Comment: And the best and *accepted* answer explains how you can move the cursor around with just spaces and '\r'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I never realized the purpose of `'/r'`!

Answer (score 2):

You can probably hack something together using the javacurses library, available here. http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/

If you haven't used curses before, it can be used to provide an interface similar to the one you might see in the BIOS menu.  It is the standard way to program menu driven text interfaces, and works for other applications as well.

Here's a solid intro to programming with curses, although actually written for the c library. http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html

Basically move a "cursor" around with `move` and add characters with `addch`, then refresh the screen.

Godspeed.