# Displaying a symbol after a certain number of spaces in java

Tags: java

My output looks like this

```
  000(05.00)      *|
  001(25.00)      ******|
  002(36.00)      **********|
```

Ideally I would like my output to be this....

```
  000(05.00)      *         |
  001(25.00)      ******    |
  002(36.00)      **********|
```

I have this as my variable...

```
  private static String MAX_REP = "|";
```

What can I do to MAX_REP to print that bar for every line at that same spot?

Comment: It is hard to answer without seeing any code...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852665/command-line-progress-bar-in-java

Comment: What was that all stars? Was that from a database column or a variable?

Comment: Maybe `String.format()`?

Comment: How are you printing the output as it stands?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15215434/1393766 maybe this will help a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, record each line as a String.

Then calculate the String's length.  Add N-k spaces before MAX_REP when you print, where N is the position you want and k is the length of the given line.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to know what you're doing, but from the looks of your output you want to fill in the number of spaces that are not occupied by stars up to some point holding `|`.

If you know the number of `*`s, then this is as simple as subtracting the number of stars `numStars` from total number of character positions `numChars` before `|`:

```
int numSpaces = numChars - numStars;
```

Then you add that many spaces. For example, using `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`:

```
String myStr = output + StringUtils.repeat("*", numStars) + StringUtils.repeat(" ", numSpaces) + "|";
```