# Libraries for constructing an interactive shell for Java application

Tags: java, libraries

I am looking for libraries for Java that will allow me to create an interactive shell. I have done some search around and have not turned up a whole lot. Most of what I have found is libraries for adding command argument parsing to my application which does not help me a lot.

The best lead I have found is a library called [Cliche](https://code.google.com/p/cliche/) which does exactly what I need. The problem is its too simple. I am looking for something that has more customization.

Has anyone come across something a little more advanced?

Comment: If you are really into customization, you may want to have a look at parboiled.

Answer (score 10):

Options to consider:

- [javacurses / JCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) - a console-based windowing toolkit, similar to the UNIX curses design
- [swing-console](https://github.com/mikera/swing-console) might be appropriate if you want a console-style view / output in a Swing GUI window. you could use this to build an interactive shell.
- [JLine](https://github.com/jline/jline2/#readme) - library for console input similar to GNU readline
- Several JVM languages offer an interactive [REPL environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) which can be used as an interactive shell, e.g. Clojure

Comment: My previous run ins with Curses in other languages proved to be a huge pain for me. But for me to get the functionality I am looking for I may have to consider it as an option.

Comment: http://www.beanshell.org/ adds a nice interactive environment, too.

Comment: As far what I read about Beanshell that seems like overkill. Its a full blown scripting to language for Java.

Answer (score 7):

We are using [Spring shell](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell#readme), and it worked really well for us. Some of its features:

- A simple, annotation driven, programming model to contribute custom
  commands
- Use of Spring's classpath scanning functionality asthe basis for a
  command plugin strategy and command develoment
- Inheritance of the Roo Shell features, most notably tab completion,
  colorization, and script execution.
- Customization of command prompt, banner, shell history file name.

Comment: In theory a nice library but a small not for future readers: Spring shell is inactive and thus won't get any updates.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435740/are-there-good-java-libraries-that-facilitate-building-command-line-applications) [JLine](https://github.com/jline/jline2/) can be a good try.

[Features of JLine](https://github.com/jline/jline2/wiki)

> - Command history - Lines that have been previously entered may be recalled and edited and can be persisted so that they are available
>     across sessions of your program.
> - Line editing - JLine allows full editing of the current command line and attempts to mimic as much of the behavior of GNU Readline as 
>     possible, including support for both emacs and vi key mappings.
> - Completion - JLine provides a pluggable mechanism for implementing command line tab completion (of course completion can be    bound to
>     any key you wish).
> - Custom Key bindings - Keys may be arbitrarily remapped to perform a specific action, and JLine attempts to honor any mapping    that is
>     set in your existing readline .inputrc file.
> - Character Masking - Input may be gathered from the user without any visual feedback. This is useful for prompting for passwords.
> - 99.99% Java - The vast portion of JLine is all Java, using only some small bit of native code, provided by the Jansi project, to
>     support Windows.

Comment: Based on what I was reading JLine looks like it would work well. The problem is the documentation seems to very scarce for the library. Also not as much of a concern but I can't seem to find any example of JLine being used.

Comment: You can see an Example in the source https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/master/src/test/java/jline/example/Example.java

Comment: The example they have does not seem to work. Instead of giving me a prompt it just runs and stops. I think Jline will work for me if I can get in touch with the devs and get some more info on how to use it. They don't seem to have a JavaDoc for JLine2 but there is one for Jline1. Thanks for the help.